# Main table update call trigger on partition

Tags: postgresql, triggers, table-partitioning

I have a table let's call it `movie` that is partitioned by genre.

I have a trigger defined on one of the partitions as follows:

```
create trigger refresh after insert or update or delete 
on movie_comedy
for each statement execute procedure refresh();
```

This trigger is used to update a materialized view.

If I do an update on `movie_comedy` the trigger is called but if I update the `movie` table the trigger doesn't get called. The updated row is on `movie_comedy` as well.

Is it possible to make this happen?

Answer (score -1):

You'd have to create a trigger on the partitioned table itself for that.